# How to jump out of the outer loop if inner' for 'loop is executed in lua

Tags: loops, lua

```
S = 'MSH, mdmOBX, TXA'
for u in string.gmatch(S, "([^,%s]+)"),1 do
    l[k] = u
    for a in string.gmatch(u,'.-([A-Z].*)'),1 do       
        g[z] = a
        print(g)
        _G["Map"..l[k]](Msg[g[z]],R[1])
    end
    _G["Map"..l[k]](Msg[l[k]],R[1])     
end
```

I have above code, I want statement outside of inner loop to be executed only if inner for loop is not executed, I tried using 'break' keyword but that did not work and control was passed to outerloop .how to fix this?

Comment: Blunt solution would be just setting some variable in inner loop body. `for condition do isInnerLoopExecuted = true end if isInnerLoopExecuted then doStatement() end`

Comment: Your title asks how to break when the inner loop *is* executed, but your actual question asks how to break then the inner loop *isn't* executed. Could you please clarify which is correct for future readers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Lua 5.2, you can just

```
goto label -- This statement goes to the jump-label label
::label:: -- The jump-label label
```

Using a flag variable which is checked after each loop which could set it for early bailout using successive `break`-statements is a classic of those fearing `goto`, or being condemned by lack of it.

```
local earlyreturn
for u in ... do
    for a in ... do
        if ... then
            earlyreturn = true
            break
        end
    end
    if earlyreturn then
        break
    end
end
```

Anyway, you could also wrap your loops in a function and use `return`.

```
function(...)
    for u in ... do
        for a in ... do
            if ... then
                return
            end
        end
    end
end(...)
```

Comment: did not understand how to integrate it in my code, elaborate, please?

Comment: uhhh... the code sample seams obfuscated enought. Also, no Lua version provided and having in mind 5.1 is still popular...

Comment: @Simrankaur: Looks like you cannot use `goto` then. but the other two solutions should still work.

Comment: Wrapping loops in a function and using return could be particularly good if you make it a local function, because you don't have to actually move the code anywhere else if you don't want to.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, to answer the "how to break out multiple loops": you can use a `goto` statement with an appropriately placed label, although it may not be the best solution. How about wrapping the body of the inner loop in an `if` instead?

Comment: So, you want to run all iterations regardless? Seems wasteful.

Comment: @Deduplicator No, in either case, it should be done so that it does **not** run (one could `break` in the `else` branch out of the *outer* loop).